# Cannot write to file in linux environment

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, google-cloud

I am using GCP Linux virtual machine and trying to execute a file and write the results into a new file. The code looks like this:

```
./segment.sh inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

However when I do this I get the message that `permission denied for outputfile.txt`

I also tried

```
sudo sh -c ./segment.sh inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

But got the same message `permission denied for outputfile.txt`

How can I write the results to `outputfile.txt`? Do I need to create an empty file `outputfile.txt` before executing the above?

Comment: I think the problem is about permissions. Can you show the output of `ls -l outputfile.txt` and `whoami` too?

Comment: There is no file outputfile.txt because the command > is to write into the new file. What do you mean by whoami? @EdgarMagallon

Comment: So I managed to execute the file after creating the outputfile.txt

Comment: 1) `whoami` is a Linux program that returns your username. 2) I think @EdgarMagallon meant this command `ls -la` which will show the current directory contents, ownership, etc. 3) The error `permission denied for outputfile.txt` means your do not have permissions to create a file in the current directory. Check the `user`, `group` and `other` permissions on the directory.

Comment: As @JohnHanley said, you should check your current directory with `ls -la` and check the write permissions and the owner and group of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information on offer, the problem seems to be that you don't have write permission to the current directory.  This answer assumes that you need to run the script from the given directory and the permissions etc are "correct".

You were pretty close with your `sudo sh` ... I think this will probably work.  Caveat is that the script runs as `root`, this might not be what you want.

```
sudo sh -c './segment.sh inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt'
```

This alternative allows the script to run as "you" with `sudo` only invoked to write the file:

```
./segment.sh inputfile.txt | sudo tee outputfile.txt >/dev/null
```

If you have a problem with the `sudo` password prompt, you could try:

```
sudo : && ./segment.sh inputfile.txt | sudo tee outputfile.txt >/dev/null
```